# Shifting GNOME 3 top-left hot corner to left screen edge

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I would like to trigger the visualization of the GNOME3 Activities Panel by moving the mouse pointer to the **left edge of the screen, instead of using the top-left screen corner**.

I have seen extensions for the customization of the screen corners (like [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/309/hot-corn-dog/)), but no extension to associate actions to the screen edges.

For reference: I am using Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 with GNOME 3.12, so I would be glad to find a solution that works on such platform.